# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания? Подскажите!

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

1. Пусть я не видел, чтоб он хоть одержал верх, но и признания поражения тоже не припомню.
2. Я не видел, чтобы отец когда-нибудь прихрамывал(,) но возможно, это так и есть.

Answer (score 1):

*Всё правильно.* Запятая в скобках нужна, потому что она разделяет две части ССП (первая с подчинительной связью). После последней запятой пропущен союз "что", отсутствие которого не отменяет запятую.